# Gradle: How can I configure repositories in buildscript block of external script

Tags: gradle

In external script common/buildversion.gradle I have:

```
buildscript {
    // Copy repositories definitions from this buildscript to all projects
    (allprojects*.repositories + [repositories]).each {
        it.configure {
           apply from: rootProject.file('../../common/repositories.gradle')
        }
    }

    dependencies { classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:1.2" }
}

apply plugin: org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin
```

In common/repositories.gradle:

```
repositories{
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
}
```

I am getting error:

> Cannot resolve external dependency
>   sonarqube-gradle-plugin because no repositories are
>   defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Externalizing sections of the buildScript block into other scripts is not supported. There is an [open defect](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2801), you should vote on it.

Comment: Repositories definitions _must_ be in a separate file.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I believe what you're asking is currently not possible. updating answer.

Comment: There actually is a way to do this. Please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45401790/1860089

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to have a single source for repositories definitions.

1. declare the repositories as an "ext" variables

   ```
   // repositories.gradle

   ext.repos = {
       maven {
           name "repo1"
           url "repo1_url"
       }
       maven {
           name "repo2"
           url "repo2_url"
       }
   }
   ```
2. "apply" in your build.gradle

   ```
   // build.gradle
   apply from: "${project.projectDir}/repositories.gradle"
   ```
3. use variable in repositories declaration

   ```
   // build.gradle
   repositories repos
   ```

Comment: Does not work in buidscript section for me: 
    Could not get unknown property 'repos' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler

Comment: Did you "apply" the repo configuration from the external file? Upload your build.gradle to github.com gust, I'll check it out.